# Strip the last hyphen(-) from phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

Strip the last hyphen(-) from phone number

I want 647-484-3839 to become 647-4843839

```
var phoneNumberInput = "647-484-3839";

var newStr = phoneNumberInput .replace(/[^-]+-$/,"");
```

Comment: only the last hyphen, or every one but the first one? Oh, and would you consider something like `6-47-48-43-8-39` to be a valid input you need to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [positive look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get `-` which doesn't follow string contains `-`.

```js
var phoneNumberInput = "647-484-3839";

var newStr = phoneNumberInput.replace(/-(?=[^-]+$)/, "");

console.log(newStr);
```

Where `[^-]+` matches any combination which doesn't include hyphen.

Comment: Wouldn't it be slightly easier to say `/-(?!.*-)/`?

Answer (score 3):

You can:

```
var pos = phoneNumberInput.lastIndexOf("-");
phoneNumberInput = phoneNumberInput.substr(0, pos) + phoneNumberInput.substr(pos + 1);
```